# Selecting selectbox options by array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting some values via **json** type ajax request with Jquery. When I use `alert(msg.options)` it alerts `["1","3","8"]`

If I use below script to select needed options, it works. It selects only options that have value 1 and 3 and 8 :

```
$('#input_6').val(["1","3","8"]);
```

But below script doesn't work even if it alerts the same:

```
$('#input_6').val(msg.options);
```

How can I fix this? Thank you...

Comment: Please show the JSON :-p

Comment: You have to parse the JSON first. `msg.options` seems to be a string. If it would be an array, `alert` would show `1,3,8`. @Falcon's answer is probably right (despite typo), no clue why he deleted it. But to be certain about this you would have to show the JSON and how you handle the response.

Comment: Oh and I just read that you are using `dataType: json` for the Ajax request. Then it seems you are building the JSON not correctly (or at least not suitable) for your situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#input_6').val($.parseJSON(msg.options));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The fact that '["1","3","8"]' was alerted instead of '1,3,8' means that msg.options is not an object but a string.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much @fd . It works. I guessed the problem something about Json but couldn't find what it is. Thanks. :)

Comment: +1 for the correct approach.. by the way you can't get notifications using `@` as the minimum are 3 letters - are you aware of this?

Comment: @Ahmet Kemal: Check how build the JSON. You can avoid the extra parsing if you build it correctly. This would really solve the problem and not just compensate it.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard no I dont know what it is. Whatelse can I use to mention fd? @Felix King I think there is no problem about Json. It works properly now. Thanks.

Comment: @Ahmet Kemal: Well, if you'd post it, we could tell but otherwise... I just assumed that the whole `msg` is what you get via your Ajax call. And if that is the case then you built your JSON in a way that `msg.options` is a string instead of an array and you should fix this. But whatever works for you :)

Comment: @Ahmet that's OK, as fd posted this answer he get notification for every comment we make here the problem is when he's commenting on someone else question or answer.

Comment: @Felix Kling oh I see :) It works fine now. And also thanks for informing about mentioning. @Shadow Wizard thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var msg = {};
    msg.options = '["1","3","8"]'
    $('#input_6').val( eval( msg.options ) );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjHUS/2/

Comment: @Sydnam thank you for help. First answer works and also simple.